# Why does QGIS try to jam some of labels to end of line geometry and not others?

Tags: qgis, labeling

My east-west (B) line is labeled as I would expect but the label for the north-south line (A) has the label stuck at the end.  This is the result of the label engine and I think (??) I have tried every combination of settings to try to figure this out.
Does anyone know why QGIS does this and how to remedy it?

[image]

Comment: Well I figured out the what but I still don't know the why.  That NW 21 etc. text labels a polygon.  The yellow lines are NOT within the polygon but if I shut the polygon labels off the labels on the yellow roads return to normal.  Still don't know why.

Comment: Try fiddling around with the priority slider in the label settings, also for your polygon the 'Discourage labels from covering features' settings options (I believe these are expanded in QGIS 3.12 to include an obstacle weight slider)